# Is there an equivalent to "agnate" for the maternal line?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

An "agnate" (Used both as a noun and adjective) is a person descended from the same male ancestor as another, **through the male line**. A "paternal kinsman" is also a way of defining "agnate."

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agnate
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agnate

Is there a similar word meaning a relative **through female line,** a "maternal kinsman"?

Comment: Upvoting for [Crusader Kings](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcrusader-kings-2%5D+agnatic) ( ಠ╭╮ರೃ)

Comment: @PatrickM lol, me too

Answer (score 13):

The word you're looking for is **enate**.

From The Free Dictionary:

e·nate  (ĭ-nāt′, ē′nāt′)
adj.
1. Growing outward.
2. also e·nat·ic (ĭ-năt′ĭk) Related on the mother's side.
n.
A relative on one's mother's side.

Comment: It was Wordsmith's word a day at one point: http://www.wordsmith.org/words/enate.html

Comment: It's a very common crossword word.

Comment: [According to Crusader Kings](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Succession#Gender_Laws), this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe "cognates"? Look at this:

> ...persons who are related through females are not agnates but are
>   otherwise relatives (*cognati*, “cognates”) by natural law. Thus, the
>   relationship between an uncle and the son of his sister is not agnate
>   but cognate. Likewise, the son of an aunt on my father’s or mother’s
>   side is not my agnate but my cognate; and in turn, of course, I am
>   related to him by the same rule.

[A Casebook on Roman Family Law](https://books.google.it/books?id=Jg8wp9crNhkC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=agnate%20females&source=bl&ots=NXLtLWaQEa&sig=M_ZVRHrowB8TGuKnF5J9UwWnpHQ&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=agnate%20females&f=false)
 
By Bruce W. Frier and Thomas A.J. McGinn

Comment: That was my feeling too, but it's too uncommon to use it in this sense. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know because English isn't my mother tongue. Hope someone else can help you. The merriam dictionary defines the word cognate as: related by blood or  related on the mother's side. But as I am not a native I don't know if there is another word

Comment: Good find. The passage makes me think "cognate" does not mean "female relatives" specifically, but just "relatives" in general.

Comment: I found another little passage that suggests that "cognate" can be used in a general meaning, or as a matrilineal counterpart to "agnate." http://gem.greenwood.com/wse/wsePrint.jsp?id=id27

Answer (score 4):

***[Matrilineality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrilineality)*** is the tracing of descent through the female line.

> - In a matrilineal descent system, an individual is considered to belong to the same descent group as her or his mother. This matrilineal descent pattern is in contrast to the more common pattern of patrilineal descent from which a family name is usually derived.
> - ***The matriline of historical nobility was also called her or his enatic or uterine ancestry*** (corresponding to the patrilineal "agnatic" ancestry).
> - In some traditional societies and cultures, membership in their groups was – and, in the following list, still is if shown in italics – inherited matrilineally. Examples include the Cherokee, Choctaw, Gitksan, Haida, Hopi, Iroquois, Lenape, Navajo and Tlingit of North America.

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

The enatic line is also known as the distaff line, since the distaff (the short rod on which fibers to be spun into yarn or thread are wound) was mostly used by women.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distaff

Comment: would this mean the agnatic line is also known as the spear line?